# wxPyDeprecationWarning in Python 3.5

Tags: python, wxpython

Works ok in Python 2.7
Trying to use wx.PyControl in Python 3.5 and get warning:

> test_direct_svg.py:20: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using deprecated class.
>   Use Control instead. wx.PyControl.**init**(self, parent, id, pos,
>   size, style, validator, name)

How do I use Control in init?

Python code I'm executing:

```
import wx

class ComponentFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        component = SvgComponent(self.panel)
        vbox.Add(component, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)

class SvgComponent(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, label="",
                 id=wx.ID_ANY,
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.NO_BORDER, validator=wx.DefaultValidator,
                 name="LoggerUI"):

        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style, validator, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        frame = ComponentFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'test rsvg', (200, 200), (400, 400))
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: read error message again - it means you have to use `wx.Control` instead of `wx.PyControl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error means you have to use `wx.Control` instead of `wx.PyControl` in all places.

BTW: don't forget `frame.Show()`

```
import wx

class ComponentFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        component = SvgComponent(self.panel)
        vbox.Add(component, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)

class SvgComponent(wx.Control):

    def __init__(self, parent, label="",
                 id=wx.ID_ANY,
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.NO_BORDER, validator=wx.DefaultValidator,
                 name="LoggerUI"):

        wx.Control.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style, validator, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ComponentFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'test rsvg', (200, 200), (400, 400))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It's currently just a warning, so "have to" may be a little strong. But it is warning you that it will eventually be removed so "should" is appropriate.